# Hidden Inputs in AngularJS Form

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I have a form where I want to submit a hidden value that is not seen (or editable) by the user.

Originally I was attempting to do it with something like:

`<input type="hidden" data-ng-model="data.selfscan" value="true">`

But looking into the issue and at previously asked/answered questions here, I learned that hidden input type doesn't work with AngularJS. So instead I needed to do something like this:

`<input type="text" data-ng-model="data.selfscan" value="true" data-ng-value="true" data-ng-show="false" />`

Unfortunately, that did not work either.

I saw another post about how I should initialize it, so I had

`<input type="text" data-ng-model="data.selfscan" data-ng-init="data.selfscan='true'" data-ng-show="false" />`

That seemed to do the trick in getting the value to appear in the form (at least when I viewed it by making the box visible), but unfortunately the init seemed to break another part of the form making the entire thing unsubmittable.

I've spent way too much time on what should be a simple thing, so I'm looking towards all of your expertise for help or suggestions of what else to try or what could be going wrong.

Comment: If you are sending data using `$http` you shouldn't need element in form at all... just send your data model and include property and value needed as part of that object

Comment: I mean all you need to do is send your `data` object and have property set on it for `data.selfscan = true`. There is no need for it in the view

Comment: And what does that mean?

Comment: The one that is bound to all the other `ng-model` in the form

Comment: Are you using `$http` or other ajax utility to submit? If so you don't need to put that property in the view at all. You don't send the form itself...you send the data bound to the form that is in your controller model

Comment: Any particular reason why not?

Comment: Then I suggest you create a custom directive and set the value within that directive. Or use css to make the input so small it isn't visible

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the form submit action in the controller.. like this.

Html:

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />      
  <input type="submit" ng-click="updateUser('hidden data')" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.updateUser = function(hidden){    
    if(hidden){
      $scope.user.other = hidden;  
    }
  };
```

Comment: I need the controller to work with two different forms: one that needs the extra hidden value and one that does not.

Comment: This would work but you'd have to make a controller function for each form.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is almost right:

```
 <input type="hidden" data-ng-value="data.selfscan" value="true">
```

As input hidden is not editable by user it does not implement two-way binding, so you need to do one way [value binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

Comment: @scflyer did you set name and or id attribute on hidden input ?